# Permisos de carpeta en ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, shell, shell-script

Buenas , tengo una instalación con ubuntu donde me dispongo a usar el apache como servidor web.

Para ello he creado una carpeta en /var/www/html/**pruebas**
Donde he creado una serie de archivos por ejemplo "indice.php"

El problema que tengo es que sino creo el archivo con el comando "sudo nano fichero.php" desde el editor no me deja crear ni editar archivos.

El usuario que uso es "edu" , y lo que he probado ha sido poner los permisos de los ficheros de dentro de la carpeta pruebas con los permisos 777 y el usuario y grupo a www-data con este comando

sudo chown www-data:www-data -R *

Esto me sirve para los ficheros que tengo creados , pero para los que "voy" creando esto no me sirve ya que debo pasar este comando cada vez.

La solución cual seria poner la carpeta /var/www/html que pertenezca al usuario "edu"?

Gracias

Comment: me a pasado parecido, yo abro el proyecto en .../html/ con un editor , y los ficheros que creo con el editor tienen permiso , solo cuando copio ficheros de otra ruta al proyecto es que tengo que darle nuevamente permiso con sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/proyecto/ para que los cargue

Answer (score 1):

Crea un nuevo directorio para tu proyecto en la raíz de apache (o donde te apetezca si vas a crear un sitio virtual). En mi caso he creado una carpeta *testsite* dentro de apache:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/testsite
```

Cambia el propietario por www-data:

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/html/testsite/
```

Cambia el grupo de usuario del directorio:

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html/testsite/
```

Configura los permisos adecuados (lectura, escritura y ejecución para usuario y grupo, sólo lectura y ejecución para el resto):

```
sudo chmod ug+w /var/www/html/testsite/
```

Asigna el “sticky bit” para el grupo (para que los archivos y directorios que se creen arrastren la propiedad del grupo www-data):

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html/testsite/
```

Asigna los permisos por defecto (para que los directorios que se creen arrastren los mismos permisos):

```
sudo setfacl -d -m g::rwx /var/www/html/testsite/
```

Ahora agrega tantos usuarios como necesites que puedan acceder en tu servidor web (en mi caso el usuario *victor*):

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data victor
```

Answer (score 1):

A efectos de desarrollo, sugiero los siguientes comandos:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chown -R tu_usuario:www-data .
sudo chmod -R 2755 .
```

Con estos comandos, estas permitido de copiar, crear, modificar y eliminar directorios y archivos dentro de '/var/www/html' o el directorio vhosts que quieras.

Para poner un servidor en produccion, es otra historia.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías configurar apache para que corra con tu usuario en lugar de www-data sin embargo supone un riesgo de seguridad y no lo recomendaría.

Para cambiar el usuario busca en este fichero: `/etc/apache2/envvars` y busca 

`export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data`

para sustituir `www-data` por `edu`

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor en este caso seria usar `PHP-FPM` que te permite ejecutar un dominio de `Apache` bajo un usuario, haciendo que toda la carpeta sean de ese usuario y eliminando lo errores derivados de `usuario:grupo`.

De esta manera tu tienes un `Pool` de `FPM` por cada usuario configurado, de manera que `Apache` ejecuta esos ficheros a través de FPM (en modo `proxy` o `.lock`) y no hay problemas de permisos.

Puedes ver como se configura aquí: https://serversforhackers.com/c/apache-and-php-fpm

Lo tienes paso por paso y veras que es muy fácil y que te quita de muchos problemas.