# Problema con permisos de mi usuario en Apache2 en ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php5, apache2, permisos

Hola a todos no consigo dar los permisos adecuados a Apache2 en Ubuntu 20.Cada vez que se crea un directorio o se sube una foto al servidor el propietario es el usuario www-data que tiene todos los permisos. Pero el resto del grupo del cual yo soy miembro solo podemos acceder a los archivos.

Los permisos se quedan así visto por consola:

```
**drwxr-sr-x   2 www-data www-data 4096 nov 30 20:18 72**
```

He seguido varias formas en internet, incluso una respuesta de aquí.
Me funcionan pero **solo para los archivos ya creados**, cada vez que sigo los pasos de varias entradas en foros, mi usuario recupera los permisos para borrar las imágenes o archivos subidos.
Pero en cuanto se crea uno nuevo, volvemos a los mismo solo el usuario www-data puede eliminarlos,etc.

[Solución a mi problema pero a mi no me funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118271/permisos-de-carpeta-en-ubuntu)

Comment: Eso dependerá también de la configuración de apache2 y php. Por defecto Ubuntu usa www-data:www-data para que funcionen todos sus archivos ubicados en el /var/www/html.  Investiga sobre los disitintos tipos de handler posibles de apache, como mod_ruid2, suPHP, etc... y tambien combinado con la directiva [Userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) para que cada usuario tenga sus propios archivos en su carpeta /home/user/public_html... Es un poco lio, pero estudiando un poco el tema lo puedes conseguir.

Comment: Gracias @masterguru lo siento pero no he podido responder antes. Lo investigare por ahí a ver si consigo solucionarlo.